# What's the meaning of num_slices parameter in sc.parallelize?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to understand what is `num_slices` argument in `sc.parallelize[T](seq: Seq[T], numSlices: Int = defaultParallelism)` for. [Docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html) say that it is

> number of partitions to divide the collection into

Imagine that I have `val a = List(0,1,2,3)` and I perform sliding operation `val b = a.sliding(2,2)`, which gives me `List(List(0,1), List(2,3))`. If I do `sc.parallelize(a, 2)`, will it be equal to `sc.parallelize(b)` in terms of partition? If not, then what does `num_slices` parameter actually do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sc.parallelize(b)` will use the `defaultParallelism` as the number of partitions, while `sc.parallelize(a, 2)` will give 2 partitions.

`defaultParallelism` can be set through the Spark configuration `spark.default.parallelism`, and is defaulted as

> Local mode: number of cores on the local machine
>
> Mesos fine grained mode: 8
>
> Others: total number of cores on all executor nodes or 2,
> whichever is larger

according to the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#execution-behavior).

PS `sc.parallelize(b)` should be `sc.parallelize(b.toList)` - I tested that the first one doesn't work due to a type mismatch: a seq is required, not an iterator.

Comment: My question regards my misunderstanding what these partitions mean. I have illustrated what partition can be made upon `a`. Is the thing that `sc.parallelize` does upon `b` same to it?

Comment: @Nourless they are different. by partitioning `a` into 2 partitions, each partition will hold 2 integers, but in `b`, each partition holds **a list** of two integers, so they are different. the data type of the RDD is different too: `a` is `RDD[Int]` but `b` is `RDD[List[Int]]`. but your understanding of partitioning is correct, as far as the concept is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

"slice" and "partitions" and "splits" are synonyms.

---

Depending on the deployment environment (local vs clustered) you observe different number of partitions by relying on the default value (which for `local` is simply the number of CPU cores on the machine).

> will it be equal to sc.parallelize(b) in terms of partition?

Not always. It depends on the partitioner (default: HashPartitioner). In other words, the default HashPartitioner will take the key of a record (if available) and hash it and place in a partition (using modulo operator).

`null`s will always end up in `0`th partition.

You may have 2 partitions (*slices*) with all elements in just single partition (say the 1st one).